# How to consume a Rest API using Zend Framework 2

Tags: php, api, zend-framework2, httprequest

Can someone provide an example to consume a third party Rest API (Ex: someurl) in Zend Framework 2. It was so simple in ZF1 using Zend_Rest. I am not looking to create rest apis in my application, just consume third party ones.

Thanks,

Answer (score 18, accepted):

```
use Zend\Http\Request;
use Zend\Http\Client;
use Zend\Stdlib\Parameters;

$request = new Request();
$request->getHeaders()->addHeaders(array(
    'Content-Type' => 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8'
));
$request->setUri($someurl);
$request->setMethod('POST');
$request->setPost(new Parameters(array('someparam' = > $somevalue)));

$client = new Client();
$response = $client->dispatch($request);
$data = json_decode($response->getBody(), true);
```