# Consume a Rest API using Zend Framework 2

Tags: php, rest, zend-framework2

Im' looking to consume a Rest API using Zend Framework 2.

I tried :

[How to consume a Rest API using Zend Framework 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21735186/how-to-consume-a-rest-api-using-zend-framework-2)

```
$request = new Request();
$request->getHeaders()->addHeaders(array(
    'Content-Type' => 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8'
));
$request->setUri($url);
$request->setMethod('POST');
$request->setPost(new Parameters(array('param1' => 'val1')));


$client = new Client($url, array(
    'sslverifypeer' => null,
    'sslallowselfsigned' => null,
));
$response = $client->dispatch($request);
$data = json_decode($response->getBody(), true);
```

Can someone provide an example how to enter username and password :

I tried this :

```
$request->getHeaders()->addHeaders(array(
    'Content-Type' => 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8',
    'user'      => 'username1',
    'password'  => 'password1'
));
```

Answer (score 2):

From https://framework.zend.com/manual/2.4/en/modules/zend.http.client.advanced.html#http-authentication

```
$client->setAuth('username1', 'password1');
```

Comment: This should work for Basic HTTP authentication - is that what you're trying to login to?

Answer (score 0):

it works now, but with curl :

```
$curl = curl_init();

curl_setopt_array($curl, array(
  CURLOPT_URL => $url,
  CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
  CURLOPT_ENCODING => "",
  CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS => 10,
  CURLOPT_TIMEOUT => 30,
  CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION => CURL_HTTP_VERSION_1_1,
  CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST => "POST",
  CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => "param1=value1",
  CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => array(
    "cache-control: no-cache",
    "content-type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded",
    "password: password01",
    "user: user01"
  ),
));

$response = curl_exec($curl);
$err = curl_error($curl);

curl_close($curl);

if ($err) {
  echo "cURL Error #:" . $err;
} else {
  echo $response;
}
```